# Update Panel Timer Problem

Tags: updatepanel

I include UpdatePanel, and I add a Timer in Update Panel,interval is 500, the timer shows current time in label , which is inside update panel too. I run my project its ok, its show current time.

BUT I include a TEXT BOX under updatePanel ( NOT INSIDE) , When I write something in text box THE blink cursor is ( | this one) escape in text box and I can not write in text box. I clikc again text box and again the blink cursor escape and I cannot write again.

I think, the timer take the FOCUS event so , each time its take the FOCUS event from text box.

How can I fix this problem, Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UpdateMode="Conditional"` for the update panels. Other wise all the update panels will be updated if any one updates itself.